# Virtual catalogs in Commerce 8.2.1

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-catalog

We are trying to work with virtual catalogs but have some trouble finding documentation on how it is supposed to work.

Our objective is just to use two base catalogs together in our storefront and thought that a virtual catalog is the best way to accomplish this? We want to merge two base catalogs into one without any price changes.

We found that the virtual catalog creates its own items with original item id and catalog name in brackets and wonder if that is optional? Example: 6042591(Habitat_Master)

The virtual catalog items doesn't contain values in Display Name or Description. Why?

When we changed anything on the item in the virtual catalog it didn't reflect in the original catalog, shouldn't it do that?

If you use a virtual catalog must we use the virtual catalog item when we add it to the cart or can we use the original catalog item?